# Injectivity radius of the Sasaki metric

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Suppose I have a compact riemannian manifold $(M,g)$. Given $g$ there is a canonical metric that we can put on $T^*M$ called the Sasaki metric for which $\\\pi: TM\rightarrow M$ is a riemannian submersion.

Now since $M$ is compact we know that the injectivity radius of $M$ is positive. However can anything be said about the injectivity radius of this sasaki metric $\tilde g$? Will it also have positive injectivity radius ? Can we relate it to the the injectivity radius of $M$?

Any enlightment is appreciated, thanks in advance.